# How to update a sequence email created by CiviCRM?

Tags: wordpress, email, civirules

I'm using WordPress 4.9.8, CiviCRM to 5.4.0, CiviRules 2.1 and E-mail API 1.17.2

I've created a sequence email by CiviRules by steps:

**Step 1**: After user added to a group G, send email 1

**Step 2**: After 5' until user added to the group G, send email 2

**Step 3**: After 10' until user added to the group G, send email 3

If I've created this sequence from start, sequence email sended ok. But if I want to update this sequence by and step like this:

**Step 4**: After 200' until user added to the group G, send email 4

This sequence created about 15' until user added to the group G, but after 200', no email send to user.

I've tried tick or untick "Don't recheck condition upon processing of delayed action" but nothing happens.

[image]

What can I do to make a sequence email and this sequence can update with CiviCRM?

---

**Update 08/08/2018**
This is conditions of my CiviRule, I have 4 Rule like that picture, the difference are the number of delay minute and the template mail.

The rule of this picture is created after my user added to group "Thông tin hữu ích". The minutes my user add to this group < 200 minutes but my user can not received email send in the rule delayed 200 minutes
[image]

Comment: Can you include a print of the conditions of your CiviRule? That might help to find out why your final mail is not sent.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've update in my question conditions of my CiviRule, I have 4 Rule like that picture, the difference are the number of delay minute and the template mail.

The rule of this picture is created after my user added to group "Thông tin hữu ích". The minutes my user add to this group < 200 minutes but my user can not received email send in the rule delayed 200 minutes

Comment: I am unclear about : "The minutes my user add to this group < 200 minutes but my user can not received email send in the rule delayed 200 minutes"?????

Comment: I mean that if I've created the rule delay 200 minute + send email before a user added to a group, after that, add user to group, the user will receive email. But if I add user to the group before create rule delay 200 minute + send email, user not received email (though time user added to group <200 minutes). Time 200 minute can change to 1 day, 1 week, 1 year. 

So I want user in group can receive email created to delay time in the future after the time the user added to group.

Comment: check my latest answer?

Comment: Thank, I've explain the difference, please check my comment below your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]I have a working CiviRule just like the one you are describing (I think) which works fine. I have not created 4 different rules but added  different actions to the same rule. There is a blog post on this here: https://civicrm.org/blog/erikhommel/using-civirules-for-a-petition-journey-at-amnesty-international-vlaanderen

I have included a screenshot of my conditions. Can you see any differences which would explain your problem? I think you need both the group checks, The one (group is) acts on the parameter from the contact add to group, the other one checks if the contact is still in the group when sending mails (to allow the opt out if the contact no longer wants to receive mail).

I also think you'd be better off by adding all 4 actions to this rule rather than have 4 rules.

I will test with the delay of 200 minutes and see if there is a problem there.

Comment: Thanks for send useful link. The difference is what happen if you update actions? "the first mail will be sent immediately, the second after 7 days, the third after 14 days, the fourth after 21 days and the fifth after 28 days". If I add the sixth email after 35 day, exist user in "Brave" group can received this email? You can test by convert day to minute. Create rule, add user and update rule with new email, can exist user receive new email?

Comment: Yes, existing user can receive new email, no problem. I will test the 200 minutes but I do not expect that to be the problem. I think the issues lies within your conditions.

Comment: I think the number 200 minutes is not the problem, too. I'll follow your guide in your link to investigate my problem, maybe in my conditions like you said. If you could, please check by create a rule send email to user add to a group (no need wait to 200 minute, only need some minutes). After that, add new email delay to the group, check if existing user in group can receive email. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking now :-) Do you mean you add an action to the rule once the rule is triggered already for a contact? In that case it will NOT send the mal. It decides what action to add to the queue based on the initial trigger. And I will try to test, but when I have time....which will probably be tomorrow.

Comment: I've test follow your guide. I only add actions to this rule not create 4 rules. It has the same result, existing user not receive mail when I update rule with new action. Maybe because of like you said: "add an action to the rule once the rule is triggered already for a contact". Could CiviRule check for send delay email by "Date Added" to group when new action update to the created rule?

Comment: No, the concept is that whatever needs to happen is triggered by an event. We do not want to change this behaviour. I think you need to rethink your rule, I am still not clear why the action needs to be added AFTER the contact is added to the group? You need to be more descriptive about your functional requirement because I am pretty sure we could meet it. Changing the engine we will never do without clearer understanding of what you want to achieve!

Comment: My case quite looks like "Petition Journey", I want to send email for user add to a group "the delayed mails are actually sent out 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 weeks later", but after 3 weeks, I realize that need to add email to week 6. So when I add email to week 6, I want to people added to group before week 6 automatic receive this email. I think after your comment, I'll send email week 6 to all users in my group after that add action send email week 6 to the rule. From that, all users added to the group will receive email from week 1 to 6. Thank you and CiviCooP create awesome extension CiviRules.

Comment: You are welcome :-) If you now want to send mails to the 'older' members of the group you can perhaps do a catch-up manual mail action? Or create an additional group 'ancientmembers'  and send email 6 out to all members of both groups or something along that line.

Comment: I'll do like you suggest. Thanks for help me understand more clearly using CiviRules. I've mark your answers is the solution for my question.